# Switching between three views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

In my application I have a main view vontroller which has another view controller, `flipsideViewController`, behind it. Upon pressing a button in the main view, it curls up and the user has access to the other view behind it.

Within the flipside view, there is a button which is supposed to switch the view to a third view controller. However, the third view comes up behind the main view and it is supposed take up the entire screen.

Comment: I didn't get you, what help do you need?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are pushing this view controllers. May be problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

A Page curl is not ment to show the entire screen, it is only ment for half or 3/4 of the screen, like in the Maps.app. If you are looking to change it, i suggest using the "Flip Horizontal" animation in this case.